# Verify signature result return 0x

Tags: go-ethereum, ethers.js, evm, 0x, multisignature

The return signature result from signMessage method obtained is 0x. How do we handle `0x` signer result from frontend?

```
const signer = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(provider).getSigner();
  try {
    const signResult = await signer.signMessage(res.nonce);
    resolve(signResult);
  } catch (error) {
    reject(error);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The return signature result from `signMessage` method being `0x` typically means that the signing operation failed or was cancelled by the user.

1. If the user cancelled the operation, you might want to display a message to the user informing them that the operation was cancelled and they need to try again.
2. If the signing operation failed due to some other reason, you should inspect the `error` object in the `catch` block to understand what went wrong.
3. Depending on the error message, you may need to debug your code or handle the specific error scenario.
4. Additionally, you may want to add a check after `signMessage` to ensure that `signResult` is not `0x`, and if it is, handle it as an error case.

Thanks.